# AVR LED running too fast!

Tags: microcontroller, avr

My LED is running too fast while asleep, and it runs as expected when it's not asleep. Strange!! What is the problem here?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/sleep.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile int8_t ss;

int main(void){

  DDRC = 1<<7;
  ASSR =  (1<<AS2);    
  TCCR2B= (1<<CS21);  //  32768/8= 4096/256=16hz  1/16=62ms
  while ( ASSR & (0x1f) );
  TIMSK2=  (1<<TOIE2); 
  sei();

  while (1){   
    set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_SAVE);  // if this line removed, LED blinks at 1hz
    sleep_enable();
    sleep_cpu();
    sleep_disable();
  }
}

// 16hz
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect){
ss++;
if(ss==16) {
  PORTD^=(1<<7);
  ss=0;
}

}
```

Comment: What is your clock source? Looks like maybe a 32.7kHz crystal from your comments? What does the datasheet say about clock operation in sleep mode? Is it perhaps switching to the internal 8Mhz (maybe divided by 8) RC oscillator when it enters sleep mode?

Comment: I think that you need to clear the Timer2 interrupt flags  TIFR2 |= (1<<TOV2); before enable TIMSK2  =  (1<<TOIE2) interrupts.

Comment: Which microcontroller?

Comment: @ajb 32k indeed;

Comment: @G36 tried that already;

Comment: @Sadat Rafi tried multiple MCU already

Comment: @Atmega328 Have you try to move the set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_SAVE)   
 and sleep_enable()  from the while loop into the mian only.

Comment: @G36 yes sir. I did that too. Feel free to test the code yourself.

Comment: @Atmega328 I will check it. Have you seen this app and the example code? https://www.microchip.com/wwwAppNotes/AppNotes.aspx?appnote=en591232

Comment: If you know the answer then you should stop asking man. Reading a code takes time. Stop playing with others.

Comment: @Jack Danniels Why not? It's an interesting and real problem.

Comment: @Sadat Rafi I am sorry boo, that you have realized your answer is too embarrassing incorrect and forced to delete it. I am not trying to embarrassing anyone here.